# Authorise users using MVC identity using PhoneGap

Tags: ajax, cordova, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am using the standard MVC 5 identity membership so users can be authenticated to use features on my site. Apart from login and register, ALL actions require someone to be logged in.

I want to use PhoneGap to take my mobile ready html and turn it into a mobile application. I intend to use ajax to do all calls to my actions.

How do I do this with the html pages not residing on the same server? How can I log someone in, and then allow them to make calls?

Comment: You can make use of WebApi

Comment: Can you find/show an example of how to use WebApi to do this? I assume you can do something like create a cookie and use that cookie for subsequent calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authenticating users from mobile devices is fairly simple with the new MVC 5 identity membership. Essentially, every HTTP request that is made to your server from a device will include a bearer token to authorize that request.
When your Web API method receives the request, it will identify the user making it via the bearer token. This allows you to use the standard `Authorize` attribute in your Web API controllers that I'm sure you're used to using in MVC controllers. Here is a [basic example](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api) of this process, but essentially it goes like this:

1. Request containing username and password is made to your server.
2. Server verifies the username/password and sends back a bearer token
3. Make another request(s) to your server to access data or other functionality, and include the bearer token in each request

Assuming you're doing this from a mobile device, some options for storing the token are HTML5 local storage, SQLLite, etc. There is no "logging in" doing it this way - there is only authorization of requests to the server. Of course, the user doesn't know that so it's very easy to simulate a typical logged on experience. Here's a brief example expanding on the one one above:

1. Create a standard login screen with fields for username and password and a login button
2. User fills it out, and when they click login you make an AJAX call to your server requesting a bearer token with the user's entered credentials (should be over HTTPS)
3. Server authenticates the credentials and you get a bearer token back. From the user's perspective, he is now "logged in".

One way to handle the bearer token from here is to store it in SQLlite or local storage so that is readily accessible for you to grab and include in any more requests to the server that you make. You just have to take into account that the token has an expiration (set by you, see that link I posted), and design your app accordingly. You might want to tighten down your security by only keeping the bearer token on the mobile device only so long as the user is using the app. When they're finished, you remove it from the storage on the device and the user must go through the authentication process (i.e "log in") again when they open the app.

Additionally, this video [Securing .Net Web APIs](http://vimeo.com/43603474) is definitely worth watching.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The link you gave me is off the back of a Web Api project so the majority of the things are missing. Its the bearer token element that confuses me, along with how to log in and what to do with that bearer token for subsequent requests (how do I store it, how do I send it etc)

Comment: @MichaelMcCabe See my edit. The link I gave you explains all of that to you except for how to store the bearer token. Really, follow along with that example and it shows you how to set up the Web API project with the OAuth token provider, how to request and get the token, and then how to use the token to authorize subsequent requests. You're post didn't include code, and I assumed you wanted a conceptual answer. If you aren't sure how to actually accomplish this via code, post what you have so far and we can work with it.

Comment: can I just say thank you for your detailed answer and help. The thing that was catching me out was the concept of "authorising" not logging in. You cleared that up. Theoretically, I now get the idea, however every example I see online is to do with a WebApi app or Single page. The MVC app is lacking all the stuff in relation to the tokens etc. I think I may have to start a new WebApi app and migrate my content over to that, unless there is an easy way you can suggest of getting this to work in a MVC app?

Comment: @MichaelMcCabe sure, just install the NuGet packages for Web API into your MVC App. After that just create a default Web APi web project with Individual Account security and make sure that your MVC project mirrors this new one's `Startup.Auth.cs`, `Startup.cs`, and `Global.asax`. Also, copy the Providers folder and the `ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs` into your MVC project. You should be good to go (after making sure any extra dependencies are installed via nuget - if any)

Comment: I feel like you're pushing webapi and OP keeps saying he's not using it yet.